# Jquery changing css and form data

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm making a form where the users fill in a title which they can size up or down. I have a preview window that changes when they click on the "size up button". But I want to store this in a hidden form to get the value when posting.

**HTML - FORM**

```
<input id="title" name="title" />
<input id="titlesize" name="titlesize" value="50" />
<div id="sizeUp">Size up!</div>
```

**HTML - PREVIEW WINDOW**

```
<h2 id="titlepreview" style="font-size: 50px;">Title</h2>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#sizeUp").click(function() {
        $("#titlepreview").css("font-size","+=5"),
        $("#titlesize").val("+=5");   // <-- Here's the problem
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this using the [.val( function(index, value) )](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-functionindex--value):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sizeUp").click(function () {
        $("#titlepreview").css("font-size", "+=5"),
        $("#titlesize").val(function (index, value) {
            return parseInt(value, 10) + 5;
        });
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DRHTw/)

Comment: @HundkartanJonas: Here's a very good resource for [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). Have a look :)

Answer (score 0):

you can get variable like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#sizeUp").click(function () {
    $("#titlepreview").css("font-size", "+=5");
    var up=parseInt(($("#titlepreview").css("font-size")),10);
    $("#titlesize").val(up);
 });
});
```

example:[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DRHTw/2/)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm not entirely sure where the problem is here, but here's a way of going about it anyway:

If you want a range of sizes so you can't get a title too big or small, you could (while this is long-winded) make a css class for each size.

Then, you could use [JqueryUI](http://jqueryui.com)'s `.addClass()` and `.removeClass`. With these you could do something like:
`$("#sizeupbutton").click(function(e){`
    `$(#title).removeClass("size45");`
    `$(#title).addClass("size50");`
`});`

Sorry if I've completely got your question wrong, but good luck!

Edit: OK, now i think i understand what you want, I would advise you check out Vucko's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You need parseInt to handle strings as numbers.

```
$("#sizeUp").click(function () {   
 var obj = $("#titlesize");
 var value = parseInt(obj.val());
 obj.val(value + 5);
});
```